# Using pandas and EWMA

Tags: python, pandas

I am accustomed to exponential moving average (EMA) being calculated the [following](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_averages) way:

```
SMA: 10 period sum / 10 

Multiplier: (2 / (Time periods + 1) ) = (2 / (10 + 1) ) = 0.1818 (18.18%)

EMA: {Close - EMA(previous day)} x multiplier + EMA(previous day).
```

Yet when I run `pd.ewma(df['Close'])` I do not see the output that matches this approach.

The following code gives me the answer I am expecting, but takes a bit longer to run.

Anyone have any pointers on what is the proper way to leverage this library to give me the output I am expecting?

```
import pandas.io.data as web

import datetime
import pandas as pd
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)

end = datetime.datetime.today()
f = web.DataReader("SPY", 'yahoo', start, end)
f['sma']=pd.rolling_mean(f['Adj Close'],10)
days=10.
alpha=(2./(days+1.))
d={}

for x in f[(f['sma']>0)].index:
    if len(d)==0:
        d[x] = f[(f.index==x)]['sma'].values[0]
    else:
        d[x] = (f[(f.index==x)]['Adj Close'].values[0] - d[dt_prior])*alpha + d[dt_prior]

    dt_prior = x
pd.Series(d)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be reading data from a constant-update web service. Can you provide some minimal, reproducible example, with expected result and actual result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you were almost on there on your own.

```
e = f['Adj Close'].ewm(span=10, min_periods=10)
```

will generate what you are looking for.  You may need to play around with adjust=True and other [parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html) to get it to exactly match the results of your for loop.  But if you compare

```
e.tail(10) 
d.tail(10)
```

you'll see that the (possibly different) starting point of the ewma doesn't matter anymore and the latest results match exactly.